# Passing objects to jQuery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

```
function unit(){
    this.html=$('<div></div>');
    this.html.click(this,function(e){
        e.data.move(e.data.x,e.data.y);
    });
}

$('#factory').click(function(){
    unit();
}
```

I'm attempting to learn OOP in Javascript. Here's a "class" for a unit in a war game that I made for practice. Each time the factory is clicked, a new unit is created. However, when I click on an old unit to move it, the newest unit is always the one that moves. So basically, `e.data` always corresponds to the newest unit, not the one which was clicked. How do I make it so that `e.data` always corresponds to the unit which was clicked?

Comment: `this` is a reference to `window` if you don't use `new` to invoke `unit();`. The way it is right now, you're overwriting `window.html` every time you click.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue. I'll accept your answer if you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a reference to `window` if you don't use `new` to invoke `unit();`. The way it is right now, you're overwriting `window.html` every time you click.

To create a new object and make `this` reference that object, do:

```
new unit();
```

Comment: You can also use [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to change `this` to whatever you want.